# Iterate via payload object v1?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

struggling a bit to do that I want, perhaps you may help me.
I have a dynamic output object with different amount of items and I don't know name of keys, so I just do output like this:

```
%dw 1.0
%Output application/json skipNullOn = "everywhere"
---
flowVars.OutputListArr orderBy $$
```

this work fine for payload like:

> ccc="333", bbb="222", aaa="111", ddd="444"

but now I have situation then one of keys is a list, but I want to return it as array, e.g.

> bbb = "221,222,223"

I can do it by

> splitBy "," ->> "['221', '222', '223']"

but don't know how to do it together.
So then input will be like that:

```
{ccc="333",bbb="221,222,223",aaa="111", ddd="441, 442, 443"}
```

I want to transform it into that:

```
"aaa": "111",
"bbb": ["221","222","223"],
"ccc": "333"
"ddd": "441, 442, 443",
```

so only bbb string get splitted (I know bbb key name)

upd: just get a situation then bbb may have only one member, so expecting a way to check key attribute name and then make it array ish... so dont belong on content it self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function that checks the type of the value and applies the right method to each one. Additionally it recurses on objects, in case there is a nested object.

Example:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%function filterKeys(o, k)
    o mapObject
            { 
                ($$): 
                    $ when ($ is :string and (k contains ($$ as :string)))
                    otherwise orderMembers($, k)
            } 
            orderBy $$

%function splitString(s) s splitBy "," map trim $

%function orderMembers(x, k)
    x match {
        a is :array -> a orderBy $,
        o is :object -> filterKeys(o, k),
        s is :string -> orderMembers(splitString(s), k)
             when s  contains ',' otherwise s,
        default -> $
    }
    
%var testData={ccc:"333", ddd: ["555", "333", "222"], bbb: "223,221,222", eee: "456, 789, 123", aaa: 11}
---
orderMembers(testData, ["bbb"])
```

Output:

```
{
  "aaa": 11,
  "bbb": "223,221,222",
  "ccc": "333",
  "ddd": [
    "222",
    "333",
    "555"
  ],
  "eee": [
    "123",
    "456",
    "789"
  ]
}
```

Update: added a key list of keys that we want to preserve, other keys that contain commas will be splitted. Note that I trimmed the splitted elements to avoid extra spaces. You can remove that if not needed.

Comment: hello, need a bit more help from you, solution you made is working but a bit not exactly as i need, could you help me to adopt it a bit? I maybe wasn't clear initially, almost all values are strings (I use numbers just to simplify) so now they all turn into arrays :D is it posible to add second check somehow like s is :string and s == "bbb" ... ? Also regardering ordering, keys comes in random order (can be ddd, bbb, ccc etc) I want them to be abc ordered - in my example it was happening right - in yours I am not sure where to add it make work

Comment: regarding order manage to make it, just added orderBy $$ at the end of function, still cant catch then key equals particular value so can split it

Comment: I moved the orderBy to the object case so it is specific for that and you don't have to remember that.
What is the criteria for strings? I modified the string condition to avoid splitting when there is not a comma in the string but I'm not sure what you want to use as a condition.

Comment: yes, that also work, you see, even if string have "," its not need to turn into array (its description field for example) so I try to catch key that have name that i know have exact list (in my scenario list of ids) so I want somehow to do like key == "bbb" only then split it, if key is aaa or ddd even if they have comma, dont split

Comment: you can add a second parameter with a list of known keys that you want to spare and modify the condition to check if the key is contained in the list and do something different.

Comment: I try to use $$ == "bbb" but that dont work for some reason its says no such variable $$

Comment: the last bit I am missing is how to check key contained something, beginner at data weaver and don't find such in documentation :( I understand that you are saying but don't know correct syntactic to add it properly, will be glad if you can add example

Comment: I will try to add something to the example when I have time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227355/discussion-between-aled-and-gorodeckij-dimitrij).

Comment: could you help me to modify this example for input as array of objects? e.g. testData = [{...}, {...}, {...}] as getting error: you can not compare value of ::object :(

Comment: Please open a new question with the new input data.